# Dynamic mapping numeric field datatypes greater than 2^63 - 1 (long type)

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, long-integer

I have the following example input data "doc".

Indexing with python elasticsearch:

```
doc =  {
    "node": [{
        "table": [{
          "node-table": {
            "packets-up": 18440044073709951615,
            "packets-down": 18447644073709991615
          }
        }]
      }]
}

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(hosts="localhost:9200")

res = es.indices.create(index="doc")

es.index(index="doc", doc_type='docs', body=doc)
```

While trying to index the data with dynamic mapping, I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 60, in <module>
    es.index(index="doc_test", doc_type='docs', body=doc)
  File "/Users/user/Projects/2018/es_test/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 76, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Projects/2018/es_test/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 319, in index
    _make_path(index, doc_type, id), params=params, body=body)
  File "/Users/user/Projects/2018/es_test/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 318, in perform_request
    status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, headers=headers, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/user/Projects/2018/es_test/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 186, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/Users/user/Projects/2018/es_test/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 125, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception', u'failed to parse')
```

I assume that this is due to the numeric values not accommodated by "long" data type.

How can we handle these numeric values.

ElasticSearch Trace:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/doc/docs?pretty' -d '
  {
    "node": [
      {
        "table": [
          {
            "node-table": {
              "packets-down": 18447644073709991615,
              "packets-up": 18440044073709951615
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
'
```

Response:

```
    {
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_state_exception",
      "reason" : "No matching token for number_type [BIG_INTEGER]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Comment: Can you show the error you get in the ES logs ?

Comment: Not getting any error on ES logs:
elastic    | [2018-11-28T08:43:25,472][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [BbQVxzK] license [4ac5ba24-82a8-4d66-8bb9-13272ca43a45] mode [basic] - valid
elastic    | [2018-11-28T08:43:25,496][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [BbQVxzK] recovered [3] indices into cluster_state
elastic    | [2018-11-28T08:43:26,313][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [BbQVxzK] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[doc][0]] ...]).

Comment: Can you enable `elasticsearch.trace` logging so we can see what get's sent ([more info](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html?highlight=logging#logging))?

Comment: @Val updated the error traceback

Comment: [Add this to your code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/example/load.py#L151-L153) but with `TRACE` level. What do you get in `/tmp/es_trace.log`?

Comment: /tmp/es_trace.log: curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/doc_test/docs?pretty' -d '[
  {
    "node": [
      {
        "table": [
          {
            "node-table": {
              "packets-down": 18447644073709991615,
              "packets-up": 18440044073709951615
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]'

Comment: You should add that to your question instead (more legible). Also please add your current mapping, i.e. what you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/doc_test/_mapping/docs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to circumvent this problem.

Option A. Store these values as float (or double) instead of long.

First you need to make sure that your `packets-down` and `packets-up` fields are mapped as `float` (or `double`), like this:

```
PUT doc_test
{
  "mappings": {
    "docs": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "bignums": {
            "match": "packets*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And then you need to wrap the number in double quotes and send them as a string:

```
doc =  {
    "node": [{
        "table": [{
          "node-table": {
            "packets-up": "18440044073709951615",
            "packets-down": "18447644073709991615"
          }
        }]
      }]
}
```

That will work and you'll be able to sum your packet field as any other field containing numeric values.

Option B. Enable [numeric detection](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#numeric-detection) (disabled by default)

```
PUT doc_test
{
  "mappings": {
    "docs": {
      "numeric_detection": true
    }
  }
}
```

And then you also need to wrap the number in double quotes and send them as a string:

```
doc =  {
    "node": [{
        "table": [{
          "node-table": {
            "packets-up": "18440044073709951615",
            "packets-down": "18447644073709991615"
          }
        }]
      }]
}
```

As a result, the big numbers will be mapped as `float`

Comment: anyway I need to modify the numeric input with quotes then?